# How can show block when mouse over icon in menu

Tags: routes, blocks

How can show block when mouse over icon in menu like this

when i put mouse in any link in this menu its show me block.

[image]

How can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a "Megamenu" type menu configuration.

You could try using a module like

- [om_maximenu](https://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu)
- [menu_minipanels](https://drupal.org/project/menu_minipanels)

To acheive that design effect.